# Naming issue in C#

Tags: c#, dll, namespaces, naming

I have a Namespace called "**Core**", which is the main namespace of my project .

Then I've created new sub namespace named "**Interface**" that will contain all GUI and WPF classes of the library . There are many `UserControl`s and `Window`s ETC .
Meanwhile i have another class named "**Interface**" which is a STATIC class that deals and managing the Interface namespace and it's features . This is designed to avoid the user\developer to manage the GUI of his software so that's why I've created this static class .

So now i have a little problem that when calling the static class Core.Interface the Compiler does not separating between the sub namespace and the static class because both have the same name exactly .

I don't want to change their names so please do not suggest any new names .
I just don't know if better to move the Interface class inside the Interface namespace or just delete the sub namespace "Interface" and move everything to the main Namespace "Core" , But then it would be a mess and I want some strict order in my project .

So what do you suggest me to do ?

UPDATE :
OK , So I am convinced from the suggestions . I will find new proper names for the sub namespaces in each case . And keep the static classes where they are in the main namespace to avoid the user defining using of the sub namespaces just to use the main static class of each one of them .

Anyway thank you guys for answering and giving suggestions .

Comment: "I don't want to change their names so please do not suggest and new names" - you *should* change your names. You're just asking for trouble having the same name (Core.Interface) being both a class and a namespace. The sooner you understand that changing names is the answer, the sooner this problem will go away. The fact that you don't *want* to change the name doesn't change the nature of the problem. And no, you shouldn't move `Interface` into the `Interface` namespace: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/09/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one.aspx

Comment: Possibly related - [How to avoid class name and namespace conflict?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4547254/1012641)

Comment: Jon , I don't want to change the name because i have many problems like this in my library for example Core.Encoder and it's static class Core.Encoder etc ... there are 4 cases like this . I don't think that giving for the classes or for the namespaces new names would be really ordered . I am thinking of moveing in each case the "manager" class inside to it's namespace , But then the user should declared use of each namespace in his code to use the static classes ....

Comment: @DavidDiamond Try focusing the namespaces along a technology name as opposed to a very defined section of your library. It sounds to me like you have lots of namespaces. Or rename `Core.Encoder` to `Core.Encoding` or something. I'd listen to Jon's advice, tweak the names and move onto coding the app proper. There is no justifiable reason for this issue to take much time.

Comment: @Adam Houldsworth , But why not just taking the Core.Interface class inside the sub namespace "Core.Interface" so it will be "Core.Interface.Interface" and problem solved ?

Comment: @DavidDiamond Jon has linked an Eric Lippert post about that. These are two bright minds in the C# world offering sound advice so I'd consider it at least. I'd personally rename `Core.Interface` namespace into `Core.Interfaces`. I personally get hung up on what I *know* are small problems, but bug me nonetheless. The **best** thing I have ever done to save my own time is to recognise and accept the fact that some things aren't ideal. So compromise (by renaming in this case) and move onto meatier problems.

Comment: @DavidDiamond: Just because you've made the same mistake in several places doesn't mean it's not a mistake. The longer you delay fixing it, the worse you'll be making it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, you should have clear difference between namespace and class. Namespaces are packages and class are thats goes in that package. for example you have a basket that contains apples and oranges, you wouldn't want to call the basket apples, do you.

If you really have to keep those names, then do not reference the namespace at the beginning with  "using Core.Interface" instead call the full class path every time you use them, this way the compiler know which one you are using.

Another options is to use an **[alias](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/c3ay4x3d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)** like `using InterfaceNameSpace = Core.Interface;`
 and use the InterfaceNameSpace definition when ever you want to use the sub class class and use the full path for the static class.

Answer (score 2):

Rename name space `Interface` to `Interfaces`; since a name space usually contains multiple classes, a suffix of `s` doesn't break semantics, might be even better.

Comment: I'd probably call it `UserInterface`, `Presentation` or something like that - `Interface` is too ambiguous a word in .NET code, given GUIs and language-level interfaces.

Comment: @JonSkeet: True, and I can't agree with you more. The answer is just personal suggestion for OP don't want to change them, this still requires change, but as minor though ..

Comment: I gave new names for each case :
Core.Encoding
Core.Hosting
Core.Tracing
Core.Interfacing ..
All ends with "ing"(verb) means a sub namespace which contains related classes to implement the name of the namespace in the project .

Comment: @DavidDiamond: Better, look around the naming of .NET Framework and you would get some idea.