# Why am I forced to use full namespaces?

Tags: c#, class, namespaces

I have created the following class:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using MyUtils.MyArgParser;

namespace MyUtils.MyImplement
{
    public static class ImplementExitOnEscape
    {
        #region ImplementExitOnEscape

        public static void Implement(Window window)
        {
            window.KeyDown += Window_KeyDown;
        }

        private static void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            var window = sender as Window;
            // Close window when pressing the escape key.
            if (e.Key == Key.Escape) if (window != null) window.Close();

            var optionX = MyArgParser.MyArgParser.GetOptionValue("optionX");
        }

        #endregion //ImplementExitOnEscape
    }
}
```

Why am I forced to use the full name space for the `MyArgParser` class in `var optionX = MyArgParser.MyArgParser.GetOptionValue("optionX");` instead of just `MyArgParser.GetOptionValue("optionX");`?

`using MyUtils.MyArgParser;` gets ignored. having it there or not wouldn't make any difference, the compiler still forces me to use the full namespace.

I find this weird because it is not happening everywhere. For example, I am not required to use the full namespace in the file where the entry point of my application is defined.

Comment: Because you named it the same as the namespace

Comment: @Patrick I though of that myself, but why doesn't it force me to use the full namespace in other parts of the program, like in the main program file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var optionX = MyArgParser.MyArgParser.GetOptionValue("optionX");
```

You class is named as your namespace, so to distinct between them you need to explicitly fully reference it.

To solve it, either change your MyArgParser namespace to (for example) MyArgParserNS and you can use it directly

```
using MyUtils.MyArgParserNS
```

And then:

```
var optionX = MyArgParser.GetOptionValue("optionX");
```

Or, well, fully reference it.

Comment: I understand, but why doesn't it force me to use the full namespace in other parts of the program, like in the main program file?

Comment: Because of the parent namespace where those other "parts" are contained. Given that are different then there's no way to confuse them (namespace vs. class) and then it enables you to call it directly.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is you have a class with the same name as its namespace, meaning the compiler cannot differentiate between MyArgParser in MyArgParser.GetOptionValue being a namespace or a class.

It may or may not force you to use the full namespace due different using statements at the top of each file or a field or variable whose name clashes with the class name. See [Eric Lippert's Blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/09/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one.aspx) (and parts [2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/11/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-two.aspx), [3](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/15/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-three.aspx) and [4](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/18/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-four.aspx)) on the subject for more information.

See [How to avoid having the same name for a class and it's namespace, such as Technology.Technology?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158092/how-to-avoid-having-the-same-name-for-a-class-and-its-namespace-such-as-techno) for more discussion on this.

Comment: Ok, but why doesn't it force me to use the full namespace in other parts of the program, like in the main program file?

Comment: @IneedHelp Without seeing the code, it is hard to be certain but I have added a few causes to the answer.

Comment: As Randolf R-F said, I realize now that I do not have to use full namespaces when operating in the namespace of the application because it wasn't sharing the `MyUtils` namespace. Thank you though for all the information you provided. +1

Comment: @IneedHelp Happy to help and glad that you found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You have your `using` directives outside your `namespace` declaration. The compiler searches for a type ***or*** namespace in these locations, in this order:

1. `MyUtils.MyImplement.ImplementExitOnEscape` (nested types inside the current type)
2. `MyUtils.MyImplement` (types or namespaces in current namespace)
3. `MyUtils` (types or namespaces in "next" outer level)
4. the null namespace or global namespace (types or namespaces)
5. `System.Windows`, `System.Windows.Input`, and `MyUtils.MyArgParser` that you have `using`s for (types or namespaces)

You entered `MyArgParser.`<something>.

In ***(3.)*** a match is found, and that is the *namespace*. Only in (5.) would your `using` matter. So `MyArgParser` refers to the namespace, not the type.

If you had put your `using`s inside the `namespace` block, things would have been different, see [an answer of mine in another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16092975/1336654).

Answer (score 0):

There could be few reasons:

1. Conflict with another name
2. Your class could be under yet another name.

Use Ctrl+J+K, and search for your class. See if VS finds it. If not, then it may be because of refercence issues. Do you need to add a reference to that library?